# Changing email smtp settings for existing account

Tags: settings, email

When setting up a new email account it is easy to enter the various smtp settings.  But I can't seem to find how to change existing settings on my existing email account.  There seems to be no "change" ability on email.

I'm using a Galaxy S3 running android 4.3
Thanks,
Gary

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Email app, press the menu key, then choose **Settings**. Pick **Account settings**, then click the account you want to change on the next screen.

After that, you have to scroll to the bottom to get **More settings**, and to the bottom again to change the **Incoming settings** and **Outgoing settings**.

Samsung appears to have taken lessons from Microsoft on hiding important settings behind "advanced" buttons!